# At what stage of math pedagogy does one learn about matrices?

Tags: matrices

In a mathematical logic class, my professor made a side remark about matrices and continued ", but you all know that." I have no clue about he was talking about, and it concerns me that everyone else did. Normally I would just peruse Wikipedia to figure out the significance of a matrix, but I think I need a person to answer this for me, since I seem to have had an incomplete education and am baffled by what I see on there.

Given that I've studied up to integration and infinite series (1 variable) and some discrete math, what should I already know about matrices, where does what I should know connect with I already know, and what are some books I can use to update myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Linear algebra... often the next course after introductory calculus.

Comment: Some times in Pre-Calculus or even College Algebra, depends on the choice of the lecturer.

Comment: Did I make a mistake taking a mathematical logic course without having taken linear algebra?

Comment: Matrices at an introductory  level are usually part of the precalculus curriculum, at least in the US. I would start with a chapter on vectors and matrices in any standard precalculus text.

Comment: I'm sure that your logic class doesn't assume anything more than the introductory concepts. In particular, unless explicitly stated in advance, there's no assumption that the students have taken Linear Algebra.